# why md-row-select not worked in md-data-table?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I use the md-data-table and md-row-select , all things worked ok but md-row-select has no effect, can some one help me? my code:

```html
<md-data-table-container>
    <table md-data-table md-row-select multiple ng-model="input.selected">
        <h3 class="md-title center"> {{domain}}</h3>
        <thead md-head>
            <tr>
                <th md-column>#</th>
                <th md-column>类型</th>
                <th md-column>线路</th>
                <th md-column>记录键</th>
                <th md-column>记录值</th>
                <th md-column>切换类型</th>
                <th md-column>切换线路</th>
                <th md-column>切换记录键</th>
                <th md-column>切换记录值</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody md-body>
            <tr md-row ng-repeat="record in diff_list" md-select="record" md-select-id="record_id" md-auto-select>
                <td md-cell>{{record.record_id}}</td>
                <td md-cell>{{ record.record_type }}</td>
                <td md-cell>{{ input.net_type_from }}</td>
                <td md-cell>{{ record.host_record }}</td>
                <td md-cell>{{ record.record_value }}</td>
                <td md-cell>{{ record.to.record_type }}</td>
                <td md-cell>{{ input.net_type_to }}</td>
                <td md-cell>{{ record.to.host_record }}</td>
                <td md-cell>{{ record.to.record_value }}</td>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</md-data-table-container>
```

Comment: can you add your controller code ?

Answer (score 0):

Make

```
md-row-select = "true"
```

This should work out.

Answer (score 0):

Make

```
ng-model="selected"
```

instead of

```
ng-model="input.selected"
```

and maybe you forget to set `$scope.selected = [ ];`